# how to add multiple batch no of the same medicin php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i am developing medical store inventory control application in php . every thing ok but i am confuse in expiry management of medicine batch wise . as the client ask me to show the expiry date of all medicine bath wise.
i m confusing how to add multiple batch no of the same medicine .
for example 
{id 1 , des  panstan , batchno b12345, expiry_date 25-04-2017}
i am calculating expiry current system date - expiry date entered 
now how to add more batch no in the same id that is 1 in this example as client ask that is every pack of the same medicine has the different batch no.[display of expiry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onZGy.jpg) [mysql table abbout batch no](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8gUx.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Use a one to many relationship. A table `medicins` for the medicin itself, with its name and description and whatever is common, and another called, as example, `medicine_packs` that references a `medicin_id` linked to the first table and everything else related to the single medicin pack.